# lazy reference: doesn't provide model user?

Tags: django, django-models

Currently I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.  I'm attempting to create a custom user model with a new application that authenticates with LDAP, but i'm greeted with the following error message.

```
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounts.user', but app 'accounts' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

Settings.py Installed Apps, Auth Backends, and Auth_User Model:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_python3_ldap',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from .models import User

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User)
```

Below is my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
```

Comment: Are you sure AUTH_USER_MODEL is set to `accounts.User` and not `accounts.user`?

Comment: I'm sure, the above is copied and pasted.

Answer (score 25):

This:

> This is caused by your settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL having changed to a model that does not exist when migrations are being computed.

... mentioned by [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) in [their answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53460421/812919) gave me an idea which worked.

I did the following:

1. Do everything to put your custom `User` model into place. Set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` and update any uses of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` with your custom user model.
2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. Undo step 1
4. Run `python manage.py migrate`
5. Redo step 1

Comment: I know this is an old answer but this was incredibly helpful to my team and I wanted to say thank you. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm failing to apply this. Here is what I did, created new users(authentication) app,  Set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` (1). Ran `makemigrations` (2). Removed `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting, commented `CustomUser` model (3). Trying to apply the migrations I encounter an error, `No migrations to apply` and instructs me to run makemigrations again and re-apply. Where am I going wrong. And also, does this solution preserve existing data? If so, where/when do I set the think to the existing  `auth_user` table? @user65909 can you assist?

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt Hi, I answered this a while ago and can't remember the details, don't think I'll be able to help, sorry!

Answer (score 10):

For me helped split on two migration

1. create new table (without connection between new and old tables and without `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'`)
2. add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to `settings.py` and other connections with new table

But it works for dev/production databases if you want to apply migrations from first in tests or another from scratch database creations you should "compact your migrations", for me it was next steps:

1. Make a dump of a database (in my case by `sqldump`)
2. Cleanup database (especially table `django_migrations`)
3. Remove all migrations in your project
4. Run `manage.py makemigrations`
5. Add migration that adds all data inserts from your old migrations
6. Run `manage.py migrate`
7. Remove table `django_migrations` in your dump (maybe some other `django_*` tables )
8. Restore your database from a dump

Comment: Also note the @daka's solution below, which does it with one migration.

Answer (score 10):

This is caused by your `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` having changed to a model that does not exist when migrations are being computed.

A slightly hacky way to fix this *without data loss, if you're migrating from auth.User to custom.User* is to add a "virtual" (separate database and state) minimal model (that is, only the ID field, to allow for foreign keys) according to the new User model in the very initial migration, so future migrations have this reference:

```
operations=[
    migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
        state_operations=[
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name="User",
                fields=[
                    (
                        "id",
                        models.AutoField(
                            auto_created=True,
                            primary_key=True,
                            serialize=False,
                            verbose_name="ID",
                        ),
                    )
                ],
                options={"db_table": "auth_user"},
                managers=[("objects", UserManager())],
            )
        ]
    ),
    # ... other migrations
```

Comment: Man, you are genius! The only solution found without that "delete all your migrations and enjoy".

Comment: I realized you can't actually run the migrations from zero to present state with this hack though, since foreign keys pointing to the user model will be broken. This can be fixable by copying the full `CreateModel` expression creating the new user model into the initial migration instead.

Comment: This is still a thing in Django 3.0.7, tried a from scratch application but my `AUTH_USER_MODEL`  never made it into the migrations.

Comment: Note that this only works when put in `0001_initial.py`. Nice fix btw

Comment: Great answer. In addition to Jurrian's note that this should go in 0001_initial.py, you should note that you also need to add "from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager" to 0001_initial.py, and modify name="User" if your user model is named something different (mine was AuthUser)

Answer (score 4):

**Warning: It will delete your whole database.** If you have some important data then backup it by dumpdata and then restore it by loaddata. [for more info check here (I am not sure about this).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rrsn2WEG5M&t=57s)

It is very difficult to change AUTH_USER_MODEL in the middle of the project. [See the note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).
Infect after you are done with your first migration of Django tables, you will face problems.

**Idea is**: You need to include your **custom user model** with its entry in setting.py (AUTH_USER_MODEL = [custom user model] ) in your first-ever migration (where django create its own table like auth_group, dajango_migrations etc... ) of Django project.

**Warning**: If you have started server then Django itself create database and then this will not work, so please do not start the server.

- Delete dbsqlite3 database file, delete all your migrations files and its binary files (In app/migration/**pycache** ) except init file and comment out all your models and it's dependencies (like, you have used model in any form then comment it also).
- Now uncomment only custom user model
- add AUTH_USER_MODEL in setting.py (AUTH_USER_MODEL = [custom user model] )
- and then run makemigrations and migrate. (this will create your all Django tables and your custom user model.)

It is done.

now you can start the server.

after that uncomment all other models and migrate them.

Comment: This may be the only solution for some situations, and if you're early in development it is definitely worth wiping out your database and getting the schema right the first time. If you are working with others, you might make a note for them not to simply pull down your code and apply migrations but to delete their local sqlite database.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can also try:

1. Do `python manage.py migrate <app_name>` on the app that contains the custom user model.
2. Do `python manage.py migrate` to apply the rest of the migrations of the app.

The reason why this works is that you're applying the changes of the new User model first before you applied the rest of the `auth` model that's built in Django.

*not sure if I explained that right*

Comment: This really helped..thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: It will destroy Your current User/Group/Auth tables and entries connected with User model**

Actually in `django 1.9+` this is enough:

- drop all `auth_*` and `django_admin_log` tables using the following statement :

`DROP TABLE django_admin_log, auth_group, auth_group_permissions, auth_permission, auth_user, auth_user_groups, auth_user_user_permissions CASCADE;`

- delete all migrations connected with `django_admin` and `auth` apps with:

`DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='admin' or app='auth';`

- Then simply run:

`./manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Easy, import to your models.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
```

then:

```py
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the below instructions

> 1. create database buckup:
>    pg_dump -U user_name -d database_name --data-only > file_name.sql
> 2. go to .sql file path  and rename using run the command:
>    sed -i 's/auth_user/custom_user/g' file_name.sql
> 3. go to sql terminal run command:
>    =# select 'drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade;'   from
>    pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';
>    =#\gexec
> 4. find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "**init**.py" -delete
> 5. find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
> 6. python manage.py makemigrations
> 7. python manage.py migrate
> 8. load the .sql file to data base using this command:
>    psql -U user_name -d database_name -f file_name.sql

Answer (score 0):

This answer works pretty good https://stackoverflow.com/a/53460421/13542023. I migrated from custom model from 3rd party library to my model and had a problem with renaming it and this helped me a lot. Also, I found interesting workaround to make running migrations from scratch possible. I make state model proxy to old one so ForeignKey and other relations work with old model during migration process.

P.S. can't put this under answer because of small reputation.

```
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='OldCustomUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'relation_to_old_db',
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            state_operations=[
                migrations.CreateModel(
                    name="User",
                    fields=[],
                    options={
                        'proxy': True,
                    },
                    bases=('users.OldCustomUser',),
                    managers=[("objects", django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager())],
                )
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error but i had to dump my data in json the delete the sqlite and the migrations

on Linux

```
 python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

on windows

```
python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata -o data.json
```

Then delete the migrations and the sqlite actually i like moving my db to somewhere else just because of safe purpose but you can delete it

After deleting then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

now you load the data but please some times the below command returns an error
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
so to fix it just open data.json in notepad and save as then you will see save as type choose  utf-8

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

After this also if you notices issues you can fix it by just editting the json its readable but sure no error

Comment: forgot to make it python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > data.json  typo i just changed the db name

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself and this is what I did to solve:

The error:

> "ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy
> reference to 'core_web.customuser', but app 'core_web' doesn't provide
> model 'customuser'."

The solution:

Make sure you have correctly updated the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting in your project's settings.py file to point to the custom user model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core_web.CustomUser'
```

Delete all the migration files for the app core_web, except for the **init**.py file, located in the core_web/migrations directory.

Run the following command to create a new set of migration files for the app core_web:

```
python manage.py makemigrations core_web
```

Apply the migrations to update the database schema:

```
python manage.py migrate core_web
```

This is what fixed it for me.

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently nothing was incorrect with the code, i just had to drop all my user tables and run makemigration and migrate.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to do that. If you do that on your local database, chances are things would end up being messed up on your DEV/PROD server.

Comment: "i just had to drop all my user tables" is a non-sensical statement. "Just" implies doing something non-invasive and trivial. Whereas you're recommending the most destructive action possible.

Comment: this is really not an option

Answer (score -1):

user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

Answer (score -3):

Remove all the **migrations** under Migration Directory

Now you can use makemigrations and migrate

Comment: Django holds a record of migrations so simply removing a directory is not something you want to do if you have a production environment and you care about changes. Also this might not help at all.