# ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm developing a new django project and stuck with migration.

I would like to make a UserModel, and in order to do that, I did two things so far.
1. I made AuthUser model and set a Meta class in the class below.

In **models.py**

```
class AuthUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=UserTypes.choices())
    user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'

    @property
    def user_type(self):
        return UserTypes(self.user_type_id)

    def original_orm(self):
        if self.user_type.value == UserTypes.raijosha.value:
            return RaijoshaUsers.objects.filter(id=self.user_id).first()
        elif self.user_type.value == UserTypes.shuttennsha.value:
            return Users.objects.filter(id=self.user_id).first()
```

2. In settings.py, I set AUTH_USER_MODEL.

   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'recommend.AuthUser'

Here's the error codes.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, recommend, recommend_raijousha, sessions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 164, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 218, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 295, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'recommend.authuser', but app 'recommend' doesn't provide model 'authuser'.
```

Could you please help us or give me an advise.

```
  Applying admin.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 254, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 144, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 994, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 991, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 909, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 653, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 640, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 625, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'recommend.authuser' cannot be resolved
```

Considering an advise, I did delete migration files.
But another error occured shown above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lazy reference: doesn't provide model user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059198/lazy-reference-doesnt-provide-model-user)

Comment: @Hadaka Kubo delete your database and migrations and create db and makemigrations and apply it.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I deleted my database and applied it. But another error occured. It said "ValueError: Related model 'recommend.authuser' cannot be resolved"
So im trying to delete all the migration files.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I could solve this problem! Thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 46):

It happens if you ran default `auth` app migrations and later changed the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`. You can try following:

```
# comment AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py so it points to default User model

python manage.py migrate auth zero

# uncomment to be AUTH_USER_MODEL='recommend.AuthUser'

python manage.py migrate auth
```

Comment: Best to also comment the model itself. Then after above two steps, uncomment and run "migrate" one last time.

Comment: This one should be valid answer instead of deleting your database and migration files.

Comment: In my case, I got the error: "auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'website.User.groups'." when running the first command.
Just added a --skip-checks and all solved. ;)

Answer (score 25):

I delete all the migration files and database and applied it.

Then I could migrate.

Comment: Haha, this wild operation worked for me. Delete all tables and migration files and then recreate migrations and apply. Only works for project in the early development phrase which has no serious data. Don't try this on you production project.

Comment: For me, only deleting migrations files was enough. It was not necessary to delete all tables. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

**Note** : I am using sqlite3 as a database.

Hi,
I easily solved it by deleting all the migration files in the migrations folder except the `__init__.py` file. And also delete `db.sqlite3`. Now run the following commands : `python manage.py makemigrations`  and then `python manage.py migrate`. Now you'll have to create the super user once again, so for this just type the following commmand : `python manage.py createsuperuser`. Then it will prompt for username, email and password, so enter your credentials and all will continue to work properly once again I hope that this will be helpful.

[Click Here To View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npEOo.png)

Comment: I tried many of the other options. This one worked for me. To summarize in a step by step format:
1) Except for __init__.py Deleting all migrations. (I missed this step)
2) Delete db.sqlite3
3) run the following commands : python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate
4) create the super user once again

Answer (score 2):

For me helped split on two migration

1. create new table (with out connection betwin new and old tables and without `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'recommend.authuser'`)
2. add AUTH_USER_MODEL to settins.py and other connections with new table

Comment: This is the easiest and safer way IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MySQL.

The solution, for me, was to delete the files inside migrations folder (all but __ init__.py), `DROP` and `CREATE` database in MySQL Workbench and run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again.

Therefore, I had to create a new superuser and all my data was lost :(

Answer (score 1):

I had to refer to [this stack:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059198/lazy-reference-doesnt-provide-model-user/51239794) to be able to solve that issue.
I simply followed the steps bellow:

---

Since I am not using sqlite, I made new database configuration that refers to my postgres, in my settings.py:

old database i am not more going to use:

> `DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'NAME': 'leszexpert', 'USER': 'postgres', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'PORT': '5432', } }`

---

new database I want to start using:

> `DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'NAME': 'leszexpert_db', 'USER': 'postgres', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'PORT': '5432', } }`

As you can see, the difference is the DATABASE NAME (referenced after ENGINE)!!!!!!

---

1. I stopped the server and already previously deleted all existing corresponding migrations.
2. I closed my IDE VScode (I have realised from experience that when something does not take effect, after closing it and reopening it, it most time ends up taking effect)
3. when I reopened the code editor, I uncomment my models (i commented them previously), then VERY VERY IMPORTANT: DO NOT START OR RUN YOUR SERVER AT THIS POINT. because now you are about to operate on the new database specified above and the issue as you know we are trying to solve is that if you run migration of that type of models after runing the server, it will not create your model...therefore DO NOT RUN SERVER YET
4. INSTEAD DO THIS: RUN MIGRATIONS AND THEN MIGRATE
5. ET VOILA (French expression to That is it): your extended user model will be created in your database:

Thank you for reading my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in development and can take the pain of filling out the db data again then here's what all you need to know!.

you need to first delete all the files related with db(including sqlite.py if it exists), you can do this by the help of below following ways.

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

Now either delete the entire data,tables of your DB or just Drop the db and make a new one and do the migrations separately for each app and migrate it.

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate appname
```

then if you get any error for the session like "ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist"

then follow these steps below:

`python manage.py migrate --fake sessions zero`

then your sessions migrate will be

```
python manage.py showmigrations
sessions
[ ] 0001_initial
```

then migrate with `--fake-initial` again
`python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

now do try to the runserver again and the problem must have been by gone now, if not then please let me know,I'll try my best possible way to solve it.

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score -1):

#### If your migration works locally and not on server do this for server;

```
root@abcomp:~/var/www/yourapp$sudo -u postgres psql
#list your databases
postgres=#\l
postgres=#\c your_dbname;
your_db=# delete from django_migrations;
# after pulling the latest working changes
(venv)root@abcomp/var/www/yourapp$./manage.py migrate --fake
```