# Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0]) in the Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need create custom user. I'm using a user model with AbstractUser:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import escape, mark_safe


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    'crispy_forms',

    'backend.classroom',
]
```

I believe that problem is in the following line:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'classroom.User'
```

error:

```
File "/home/davi/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-vue-template-Wl6a6m2J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 82, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/davi/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-vue-template-Wl6a6m2J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/davi/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-vue-template-Wl6a6m2J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/davi/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-vue-template-Wl6a6m2J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 226, in build_graph
    self.add_external_dependencies(key, migration)
  File "/home/davi/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-vue-template-Wl6a6m2J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in add_external_dependencies
    parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
  File "/home/davi/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-vue-template-Wl6a6m2J/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 173, in check_key
    raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: classroom
```

obs: The app classrom app is in the backend folder. I tried the following code too:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.classroom.User'
```

Comment: Did you `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: And yes, if your app is "backend.classroom", then the model would be "backend.classroom.User"

Comment: I _assume_ the app is actually `classroom` and there are backend and frontend directories, one for a Django app, one for whatever frontend code.

Comment: Are you making this change to an existing app where you already had a user model?

Comment: Yes, but show errors and with AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.classroom.User'

Answer (score 9):

Try creating the initial migration for the `classroom` app before declaring it as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, as anything that would ordinarily depend on `auth.User` now depends on `classroom.User`.

```sh
$ python manage.py makemigrations classroom
```

Comment: Quoting the Django docs: "Don’t forget to point AUTH_USER_MODEL to it. Do this _before_ creating any migrations or running `manage.py migrate` for the first time." It would be a mess to run migrations before setting the AUTH_USER_MODEL as that would create the User table with the wrong model. It wouldn't matter for the `makemigrations` command, but adding a custom User model in an existing app [isn't a straightforward undertaking](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).

Comment: Good point well made, @dirkgroten. I actually have an answer relevant to that situation here, since I had to wrangle it with myself... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059198/lazy-reference-doesnt-provide-model-user/53460421#53460421

Comment: I hope the OP is on a new project, not an existing one :-) but I hadn't seen the `migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState` trick before, pretty cool.

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648393/how-to-move-a-model-between-two-django-apps-django-1-7

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on the app install i think?
You are having classroom as app right? and the backend the project? if so then the correct
configuration
so the install app should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    django.contrib.auth,
    django.contrib.contenttypes,
    django.contrib.sessions,
    django.contrib.messages,
    django.contrib.staticfiles,
    django.contrib.humanize,
    crispy_forms
    classroom,
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = classroom.User #classroom is app while User is the model
```