# Django ValueError 'accounts.user', but app 'accounts' isn't installed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Few days I write an app to extends User Model, it is simple and worked nice. later I push to the GitHub and delete from my local machine.

Now I have cloned that app again to my machine and tried to migrate and run server but it returns this error:

```
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounts.user', but app 'accounts' isn't installed.
```

My Installed apps these:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accountsapp'
]
```

I am not getting where the project got apps name `accounts` this is very odd error i seen ever.

If you want to see my entire project, go there:

[Porjects on Github, click here to see](https://github.com/MySecondLanguage/Django-Custom-User-Model-Version-One)

You will see how simple this apps.

Even i have deleted previos db file, pychch, migrations history etc, not getting why it is not working

Answer (score 1):

There are no migrations in your project. So there was no table for `MyUser` created. You need to make the migrations first and run them.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: That is what i said already, i cant even migrate or migrations, it retruns the same error, you can try it cloning my project from github

Comment: try adding `accounts` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Try making the migrations without the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting. Also, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059198/lazy-reference-doesnt-provide-model-user